# Vertically centering faux-absolute-positioned (float: left) elements

Tags: css, css-float, center, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to display a semitransparent grid of captioned images physically underneath a "lightbox"/overlay with my actual content in it. The font size in the document is generally set using `vw` units, so the height of the overlay changes depending on the screen resolution.

I want to vertically center whichever happens to be smaller - the background image grid, or my overlay. If the *text* in the *overlay* is bigger (`font-size`-wise), I want the grid to vertically center relative to the *overlay*, but if the *grid* is bigger I want the overlay to vertically center relative to the *grid*.

Initially I tried using `position: absolute` on the overlay which of course failed epically when I discovered the text in said overlay would overlap the content below the grid if its `font-size` got too big. I'm currently using [Faux Absolute Positioning](http://alistapart.com/article/fauxabsolutepositioning) ([demo](http://d.alistapart.com/fauxabsolutepositioning/sapdemo-fivecol-liquid.html)) which has resolved the overlap problem (the content is pushed down by whichever is bigger, my grid or the my lightbox, but I simply haven't been able to combine this neat trick with any of the float-vertical-centering demos/examples I've found on SO and elsewhere.

The grid is currently a table (which took me quite a while to figure out!), but I could switch to some other method (a very long series of `float`s, for example) if absolutely necessary. (The grid is very arguably tabular data, in my opinion.)

This is for a non-public document I'm sending somebody which I'm authoring using HTML5/CSS3 for rich layout/styling/formatting, so my rules of "strict semantics" are slightly (okay, quite) relaxed in this situation. (LaTeX->PDF would be impossible - constantly restarting `xpdf` to reload my PDF would progressively drive me so far up the wall I'd drill a hole in the ceiling with my head - and LibreOffice would probably choke on the ~150+ images I'm dealing with. And besides, the document is full of progressively accrued CSS3 awesomeness I would have to leave behind if I switched to PDF/ODT...)